# is it possible to open apple watch app from iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, watchkit

I was just wondering if there's is any way to start an apple watch application from iphone app.i.e, suppose if i had developed an i-phone app which displays calories burned, by clicking on startworkout and had a button "Send to watch" which starts the same workout app on the apple watch without user interacting with the watch. I should be able to see the same data getting displayed on iphone app.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you've described isn't possible in either watchOS 1 or watchOS 2.